# add a list_mode in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-enterprise, php, toolbar

There are basically two list_modes in product/list/toolbar .
I want to add a third mode Gallery mode so that switcher can switch between

1- Grid,
2- List,
3- Gallery when products are listed.
Is this can be done through xml or by adding a value in db as code ??

Answer (score 1):

Have not done this myself, but a quick search for the term 'List Mode' in core files (search *.xml) reveals that the list mode is done via `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Catalog_ListMode`

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Catalog_ListMode
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            //array('value'=>'', 'label'=>''),
            array('value'=>'grid', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Grid Only')),
            array('value'=>'list', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('List Only')),
            array('value'=>'grid-list', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Grid (default) / List')),
            array('value'=>'list-grid', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('List (default) / Grid')),
        );
    }
}
```

You will thus need to extend (rewrite) that class with your own, and add your new list mode:

```
class YourModule_YourNameSpace_Model_System_Config_Source_Catalog_ListMode extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Catalog_ListMode
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $listModes = parent::toOptionArray();
        return array_merge($listModes,array('value'=>'gallery', 'label'=>Mage::helper('yournamespace')->__('Gallery')))
    }
}
```

you will then need to copy the template file `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml` and in it add a new conditional to test for your new type, and add in the code to deal with it.

You can use the relevant layout xml files to attach your gallery blocks as child blocks to the list view, and can thus use a simple ->getChildHtml('gallery') to display your code, or simply just place your html in the template. I will opt for the first, as it is a bit 'neater'

Comment: You should be able to do this without a rewrite. In your module's system.xml you can just replace the source_model of the nodes where you want to use this (catalog/frontend/list_mode).