# Cannot access custom category list mode on frontend (Grid, List, etc...)

Tags: magento-1.9, list-view

I tried [add a list_mode in magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12216/add-a-list-mode-in-magento) but all that this was able to accomplish (for me, on v1.9.1.0) was appending the list in Configuration > System > Catalog > Front End > List Mode. I saved the new setting but when echoing "$this->getMode()" nothing is returned unless I select one of the grid or list options.

\app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Model\System\Config\Source\Catalog\ListMode.php

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Catalog_ListMode
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            //array('value'=>'', 'label'=>''),
            array('value'=>'grid', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Grid Only')),
            array('value'=>'list', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('List Only')),
            array('value'=>'slider', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Slider Only')),
            array('value'=>'grid-list', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Grid (default) / List')),
            array('value'=>'list-grid', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('List (default) / Grid')),
            array('value'=>'slider-grid-list', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Slider (default) / Grid / List')),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved:

Needed to add to the list of acceptable views.

/home/user/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php

```
/**
 * Init Toolbar
 *
 */
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->_orderField  = Mage::getStoreConfig(
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Config::XML_PATH_LIST_DEFAULT_SORT_BY
    );

    $this->_availableOrder = $this->_getConfig()->getAttributeUsedForSortByArray();

    switch (Mage::getStoreConfig('catalog/frontend/list_mode')) {
        case 'slider':
            $this->_availableMode = array('slider' => $this->__('Slider'));
            break;

        case 'grid':
            $this->_availableMode = array('grid' => $this->__('Grid'));
            break;

        case 'list':
            $this->_availableMode = array('list' => $this->__('List'));
            break;

        case 'grid-list':
            $this->_availableMode = array('grid' => $this->__('Grid'), 'list' =>  $this->__('List'));
            break;

        case 'list-grid':
            $this->_availableMode = array('list' => $this->__('List'), 'grid' => $this->__('Grid'));
            break;

        case 'slider-grid-list':
            $this->_availableMode = array('slider' => $this->__('Slider'), 'grid' => $this->__('Grid'), 'list' => $this->__('List'));
            break;
    }
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml');
}
```